# How to compile a Frama-C plug-in having a C source?

Tags: frama-c

I created a Frama-C plug-in which uses a `.c` source and I'd like to compile it, but when adding

```
PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT = file
```

to my plug-in's Makefile, I obtain the following error after running `make`:

```
Packing      Myplugin.cmx
file.c:1:24: fatal error: caml/alloc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <caml/alloc.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

Adding `VERBOSEMAKE=yes` gives some additional information about the error cause:

```
...
gcc     file.c   -o file
file.c:1:24: fatal error: caml/alloc.h: No such file or directory
...
```

It seems that GCC is being called for some reason, instead of `ocamlc`.

How can I tell make to correctly compile my `.c` sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the right syntax for the `PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT` variable is to include the `.o` extension:

```
PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT = file.o
```

By doing so, Make applies the right rule and builds `file.o` using `ocamlc`, and then includes it as an additional argument to the `ocamlopt` command which builds the plug-in's `.cmx` file.

The previous error was caused by the fact that Make applied an implicit rule to the non-existing `file` target, as demonstrated by running `make -d`:

```
...
Considering target file `file'.
 File `file' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `file'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `file'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `file.c'.
 Found an implicit rule for `file'.
...
```